# Is it possible to fake Internet traffic?

Tags: internet-connection, network-traffic

I'm looking for a way to fake my Internet traffic so that any connections made to other websites on the Internet will look like a static connection. (i.e when i'm downloading files or visiting pages from website X or Y, the ISP will see that I'm interacting with website Z. my mobile 4G provider gives free Internet access to certain mobile apps and any connection made to those apps are free of charge. I want to do this on Windows 8.1. I couldn't find any useful information, all I found was about bots for website traffic etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why it's impossible? VPN? Proxy?

Comment: you can't fake the traffic, the real traffic has to go through the server Z. Proxy or VPN *might* work but you need to have control of server Z to install such software on it.

Comment: So you're asking people here to help you violate the terms of service you agreed to?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking how to do ‘illegal activity’ (http://meta.superuser.com/a/9294/150988).

Comment: Ok do whatever you want. you look so offended. lol :)

Comment: Tunnelbear does this.  Check them out in the Android Play Store.  There is the main app then the one that fakes normal traffic and the VPN stuff is hidden inside it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your Internet traffic is passing through your ISP, so unless it's encrypted he knows its destination. To use website X you must specify that you want to use website X because your ISP has to know where to pass your traffic.

A [web proxy](http://proxy.org) is an option if it supports HTTPS, otherwise it's not encrypted and can be viewed by ISP. VPN and proxies aren't websites, but services and they could work.

The problem is: probably none of these is offered by the apps that you can use for free. All in all, what you want to achieve is not possible.

Comment: Tunnelbear does this.  Check them out in the Android Play Store.  There is the main app then the one that fakes normal traffic and the VPN stuff is hidden inside it..